# Receiving escaped double quotation marks using HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I call a page using HttpWebRequest and then I retrieve the HTML using HttpWebResponse. Everything works fine, except I don't understand why the HTML code i retrieve is 'weird'.

Example:

```
http:\/\/www.example.com\/link\/
```

is actually

```
http://www.example.com/link
```

another example:

```
\u00252Crandom_data
```

is actually

```
%2Crandom_data
```

thanks for the edit, sorry I'm new.

Beginning of HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*
```

the data that's weird is inside this

```
window.location.replace
```

Comment: maybe C# is encoding it for you to make it safe for web transmission?

Comment: All other sites work fine. Is it possible that it's related to javascript? See edit.

Comment: Are you looking at the string in the debugger?

Comment: @slaks No. I'll try and report back.

Comment: @Slaks The string is exactly the same in the debugger. I'm thinking that js has something to do with this.

Comment: @phpnewbie: it's not necessary to put "C#" in the title, since you've already got it in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing a Javascript string with escape codes.

That's the actual page source.

Comment: So I guess I have to parse the data myself out, that's gonna be annoying. Thanks!